# Passing parameters to controller through ajax request in rails application

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I need to pass a data through ajax to the controller.
I have this in the page */admin/projects/report_project_resources.html.erb*

```
<%= select("project", "report", Project.where(closed: false).collect { |p| [ p.name, p.id ] }, { prompt: "Seleziona un piano formativo" }) %>

<div id="hiddenField" style="display: none">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div style="margin: 20px 20px;">
                <%= link_to 'Genera report', generate_project_resource_associations_admin_projects_path, :class => "btn btn-default" %>
            </div>
            <div class="box">
                <!-- /.box-header -->
                <div class="box-body" id="table-box">
                    <%= render :partial => "table" %>
                </div>
                <!-- /.box-body -->
            </div>
        <!-- /.box -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

when I select a project from the list, I will show the partial */admin/projects/_table*, so I use the following script:

```
$("#project_report").change(function(){
    if ($(this).val() !== '') {
        $("#hiddenField").show();
        var project_id = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/admin/projects/report_project_resources.js",
            data: {
                projectId: project_id
            }
        });
        console.log(data);
    }
    else if ($(this).val() === '') {
        $("#hiddenField").hide();
    }
});
```

I have a */admin/projects/report_project_resources.js.erb* file with:

```
$('#table-box').html("<%= escape_javascript (render partial: 'table') %>");
```

to open my partial.
In my partial *_table* file now I have only the following:

```
<h1><%= params[:projectId] %></h1>
```

to test the params passed.
If I try to store the params in a variable inside the controller I can't. I tried writing in the */admin/projects/projects_controller.rb*:

```
  def report_project_resources
    @project = params[:projectId]
    project = Project.find_by(id: @project)
  end
```

but I can't see the project found by **@project**.
Someone can help me please? Thank you.

Comment: You don't provide us with that many debugging details. *"Can't see the project"* covers a pretty large gap. Have you checked the if the request is successfully executed? Go to your web-browser development tools and look under network requests if a request is made and what the response is. The next thing to check would be if the returned JavaScript actually executes. You can do this easily by placing the line `console.log("Hello World!")` as the first line of *report_project_resources.js.erb*.

Comment: If the above al is successful make sure you have some non-variable content above or below the variable content. For example start your *_table* partial with `<h1>Hello World!</h1>` to make sure it renders. This way you don't depend on variables to display something. If you JavaScript selectors are correct you should see this content appear on your page. You can then start testing if your variables contain the values they are supposed to contain.

Comment: Thank you, all this works. I can see the ```console.log("Hello World!")``` and also the ```<h1>Hello World!</h1> ``` as the title of the partial __table_.
But I can also see the params ```params[:projectId]``` passed in my __table_ partial, but if I try to use it in the controller it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you aware that the project found by `project = Project.find_by(id: @project)` is stored in a local variable? And thus not accessible via the view/partials. Did you mean to use `@project = Project.find_by(id: params[:projectId])`? You need the `@` if you want to access a variable from the view or a partial. What do you mean with *"doesn't work"*? Do you mean that `params[:projectId]` is `nil` within the controller? Have you set a breakpoint in the controller action and inspected `params`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm still pretty new at this but could this be of help?

`config/routes.rb`

```rb
get :report_project_resources, to: "projects#report_project_resources", as: :report_project_resources
```

`report_project_resources.html.erb`

```html
<%= select_tag "project", options_from_collection_for_select(Project.all, "id", "name"), prompt: "Select something", id: "project-select" %>

<div class="box-body" id="table-box">
  <%= render partial: "shared/table", locals: { report: "" } %>
</div>
```

`shared/_table.html.erb` (partial)

```html
<h1><%= report.present? ? report.name : "None" %></h1>
```

`projects/projects_controller.rb`

```rb
def report_project_resources
  @report = params[:projectId].present? ? Report.find_by(project_id: params[:projectId]) : ""
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render partial: "shared/table", locals: { report: @report } }
  end
end
```

`app/assets/javascripts/projects.js`

```js
$('#project-select').on('change', function (){
   var project_id = $(this).val();
   $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: "/report_project_resources",
       data: { projectId: project_id }
   }).done(function(result) {
      $("#table-box").html(result);
   }).fail(function() {
       console.log("error")
   });
 });
```

Maybe it's not exactly how you want it but hopefully it helps! :)